# Why there is additional 4px height for div when there is svg inside it?

Tags: html, css, svg

i have div element with `width: 100px` and `aspect-ratio: 1`, but why when i add svg inside it, it's height become `104px`?

this is the code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    width: 100px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background: red;
  }

  svg {
    background: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, SVG elements are inline elements, meaning they have a default `display` value of `inline` and they sort of behave like text. As a result, inline SVG elements are subject to the styling effects of `line-height`, which in browsers typically defaults to `normal` or something slightly larger than `1`. This means that in addition to the 100px of height provided by the SVG element, the line it's in will also add a little height.

There are a couple of approaches to fix this. First, you can set the `line-height` of your container to `0` in CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the `display` value of your SVG elements to some type of `block`, or `vertical-align` to `top`:

```css
svg {
  display: block; /* or inline-block, or */
  vertical-align: top;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: wow, it works! i have been looking the answer for this behavior, but never solve it. how do  you know this? is there any documentation for this? just want to know

Comment: You could potentially extract this behavior from the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) and [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) documentation, but personally, my knowledge mostly just comes from experience and randomly stumbling across it one day.